# Getting to Windows 7 shutdown menu with the keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

On my Windows XP I simply press <kbd>Start</kbd> -> <kbd>U</kbd> to see the Windows shutdown menu, so I can choose whether to shut down or restart or standby or whatever.

Is there a similarly elegant way to do that on Windows 7, without touching the mouse?

Comment: just press and hold the power button for 5 seconds

Comment: just press the power button once ;-)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. Attempting to close the shell should display the shutdown dialog.

Comment: This work on pretty much ANY version of windows.

Comment: Bear in mind that this WONT work if you had pressed WIN+D once BEFORE this sequence. [WIN],[ESCAPE],[ALT]+[F4] is a more robust solution which you know will work even when you can't see the screen. You send ALT-F4 to the start button.

Comment: Shorter is to **hit `Win` followed by `ALT`+`F4` twice**.

Comment: +1 for getting me to close my web broaswer because I didn't hit Win D first...

Comment: For me, this popups an alert `Are you sure you want to exit Virtuawin`.

Comment: @tylerl, yours won't work after having pressed WIN once :)

Answer (score 52):

<kbd>Win</kbd> , <kbd>→</kbd> , <kbd>space</kbd> = shutdown

<kbd>Win</kbd> , <kbd>→</kbd> , <kbd>→</kbd>  = shutdown menu (<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> to navigate)

Comment: Don't forget to mention that shutdown is still accessible from Ctrl+Alt+Del, using tab or the arrow keys.

Comment: Actually, the first combination executes the default action (that can be overridden to be *Sleep*, for instance)

Comment: It's worth to change the default action to lock in order to avoid accidental shut downs. This happened to me more than once, before I changed it. After the change the items in the shutdown menu are still accessible with the keyboard via their shortcut key (u - shutdown, s - sleep, h -hibernate, etc.)

Answer (score 26):

- <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>
- type `shutdown -t 0`
- <kbd>enter</kbd>

[About the shutdown command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: +1 for command line goodness and `shutdown -f -t 0` will make sure this happens

Answer (score 15):

in order (not together)

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>
2. <kbd>→</kbd>
3. <kbd>→</kbd>
4. <kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: thanks, Jeff. I've yet to take the time to learn all the nuances of this site.

Comment: +1 for explaining "in order (not together)".  I didn't understand the answers above till you pointed this out.

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>.

This way is useful if you want to shut down *without* installing Windows Updates: Normally Windows 7 has no way to shut down without installing updates like XP did, but this way you can get to a shutdown menu with separate entries for **Shut down** and **Shut down after installing updates**.

Comment: This doesn't work if [Process Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) is wired up for Ctrl+Alt+Del (menu Options/Replace Task Manager).

Answer (score 7):

Why not just configure your power button to shut your computer down? Just go to "Control Panel"/"Power Options" and click on "Chose what the power buttons do".

Alternatively, I just press <kbd>Win</kbd>, left arrow key (followed the left arrow key again and the up arrow, if shutdown is not your default option!)

Comment: Perhaps because for the same reason that xe doesn't want to move xyr hands from the keyboard to the mouse, xe doesn't want to bend down and grope blindly under the desk to reach the power button on the case that is sitting on the floor.  Not everyone has a laptop or a Microsoft keyboard, you know. ☺

Answer (score 2):

If you have [Process Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) installed and running:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to Process Explorer
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>

Comment: Brilliant - simple to learn and involves "only" 5 keypresses. I can hear the whole planet running towards their nearest Apple stores ...

Answer (score 2):

I got very fed-up with the Windows 7 Start Menu, its look and behaviour upset the tricks I've learnt since Windows 3.1. So I installed <strike>[Classic Start Menu]</strike> [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net) and got the old style menu back. Try it, you might like it.

It's lightweight, reliable and eminently configurable and your fancy-schmancy Windows 7 Start Menu is still there. I have mine set-up so Option + Click instantly displays it.

UPDATE:

I have switched to [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/) which is **even better** than Classic Start Menu. All the above applies and more!

[In case anyone marks this as spam I'd just like to state that I have *absolutely no connection* with the organisation that produces it and you're welcome to contact me for further details if you like.]

Comment: I found something similar. You It is a direct way of reverting back to the Classic Start Menu. But I haven't tested it. Here's my blog post that links to it (the original was written in German, in 2009)  https://sites.google.com/site/dataanxiety/blog/desperatelyseekingtheclassicstartmenuinwindows7

Comment: Why not uninstall and use Win 3.1? It is *guaranteed* to keep those tricks you love :)

Comment: Why not go back to notebook and pen? *Guaranteed* not to bluescreen every hour ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a keyboarder so I will do anything to keep from using the mouse.  I find that if my pointer is actively on the desktop, the old Alt F4 works for me every time.  Alternately, Windows key followed by a right arrow and then the enter key works for me as I have my system configured now.